# How to round to 2 decimals during calculation in Java

Tags: java, android

For one calculation I need to round to 2 decimals during the calculation.

Relevant code:

```
count = 500;
price = 0.00077
pounds = 150,000
double value = ((350 - count) * price) * (pounds / 100);
```

To get the result I need, `(350 - count) * price` must round to 2 decimal places before doing the `pounds / 100` so how might i round to 2 decimal places during a calculation?

Comment: `Math.round(((350 - count) * price)*100d)/100d`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java you can round it some think like that

```
double roundOff = Math.round(a * 100.0) / 100.0;
```

in your case

```
Math.round(((350 - count) * price) * 100d) / 100d
```

Comment: That did exactly what i needed. Thanks very much.

Comment: @Atrus Err, no. This fails most of the time, and the more precisio you want, the more it fails. See my answer in the duplicate.